# How to best categorize values in a table

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of designing a new database for a project at work. I want to create a table that stores Assignments for a digital classroom. Each Assignment can be one of 2 categories: *"Individual"* or *"Group"*.

The first implementation that comes to mind is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `assignments` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'individual',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category_index` (`category`(10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I would then select all assignments of a given category with:

```
SELECT title FROM assignments WHERE category = "individual"
```

However, because we've had performance issues in the past, I'm trying to optimize the design as much as possible. As such, I'm wondering whether or not storing the `category` as a `VARCHAR` is a good idea (considering the table will get quite large)? Would indexing an `INT` perform better over a `VARCHAR`?

Aside from just performance, I'm also curious what would be considered a good solution from a design-perspective. Suggestions?

Comment: You could also throw ENUM into your considerations

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I read about that briefly somewhere, but it seemed largely discouraged. I'll look into that more.

Comment: That was not a recommendation, just another option

Comment: @RiggsFolly, fair enough. Do you have any recommendations though?

Comment: I suspect that switching to an INT will provide a performance advantage, but only a very marginal one.

Comment: If I were you, I would prefer storing the category as `small integer` and create another `category` table and create a foreign key between them for integrity. Then I would create a view to join two tables. This would be better regarding resource usage but this is not the best way

Comment: @ozy, right, I thought of this as well (though, not the view part). It just feels counterintuitive to create a table for, what essentially is, a binary value.

Comment: @Chris, profiling the query with huge amount of generated data for different alternative scenarios can help you. For some cases, normalization does not help, though.